# Force make clean and remake if specific marker file is missing

Tags: gnu-make

I have a Makefile that I run with multithreading (`-j8` specifically).

I want to force a `make clean` and `make all` operation if I'm missing a specific marker file identifying the version compiled.
(This file should be introduced when the make is completed after the second `make all`.)

I can't seem to make this work properly. I either get stuck in loops or it just doesn't happen at all.
(This is part of a huge system so I can't just change any paradigms and I have to work with what I have)

Here's the relevant section I have so far. This wasn't the original plan but I shifted so many things around this is the current situation:

```
VERSION = 2.8
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY : all
all : {some targets} | marker_file

###########################

.PHONY : marker_file
marker_file : build/$(VERSION).marker

.PHONY : check_marker
check_marker :
        ifeq (,$(wildcard build/$(VERSION).marker))
        @echo -e "\e[41mYOU ARE ON NEW PREREQUISITES $(VERSION)! FORCING MAKE CLEAN BEFORE REBUILDING\e[0m"
        $(MAKE) clean
        @mkdir -p build
        @touch build/$(VERSION).marker
        $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS)
        endif

# if the marker file needs generation, force clean and rebuild
build/$(VERSION).marker : check_marker
```

Can anyone figure out how to properly plan the rules and dependencies so that I can generate the file on the second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use order-only prerequisites.  That forces the prerequisite to always run, but doesn't use the results in determining whether to run the target.  That's almost the exact opposite of what you want.

Also you cannot use make preprocessor constructs like `ifeq` inside a recipe (indented by a TAB).  Recipes are passed to the shell, and the shell is not make and does not understand make constructs like `ifeq`.

You can use make's auto-re-exec feature: if an included file changes then make will re-exec itself.  So:

```
VERSION = 2.8
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY : all
all : {some targets}

###########################

MARKER_FILE = build/$(VERSION).marker

$(MARKER_FILE) :
        @echo -e "\e[41mYOU ARE ON NEW PREREQUISITES $(VERSION)! FORCING MAKE CLEAN BEFORE REBUILDING\e[0m"
        $(MAKE) clean MARKER_FILE=
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        @touch $@

include $(MARKER_FILE)
```